# Get the server URL in a script

Tags: rundeck

How do I get the server URL in a script?

I can get the project @job.project@ and id @job.id@, but I would like to get the URL.

we have different instances for dev vs prod, and I want to include a link to the job in the output that is logged in a different system without needing to update the script when it rolls out.

Comment: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6969 <- submitted the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suggest that [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues).

Alternatively, you can extract the value from the `rundeck-config.properties` file and store it on a [data](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/log-filters/key-value-data.html#key-value-data) value (to use in any step/job later), I leave a job definition example:

Command Step:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>e8bb217c-ec91-418a-aec5-16df83dbcf82</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>RundeckServerName</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <plugins>
          <LogFilter type='key-value-data'>
            <config>
              <invalidKeyPattern>\s|\$|\{|\}|\\</invalidKeyPattern>
              <logData>true</logData>
              <regex>^(grails.serverURL)=*(.+)$</regex>
            </config>
          </LogFilter>
        </plugins>
        <script><![CDATA[cat /etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties | grep 'grails.serverURL']]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "the rundeck server url is: ${data.grails.serverURL}"</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>e8bb217c-ec91-418a-aec5-16df83dbcf82</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Script step:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>e8bb217c-ec91-418a-aec5-16df83dbcf82</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>RundeckServerName</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <plugins>
          <LogFilter type='key-value-data'>
            <config>
              <invalidKeyPattern>\s|\$|\{|\}|\\</invalidKeyPattern>
              <logData>true</logData>
              <regex>^(grails.serverURL)=*(.+)$</regex>
            </config>
          </LogFilter>
        </plugins>
        <script><![CDATA[cat /etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties | grep 'grails.serverURL']]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[echo "Rundeck URL is: @data.grails.serverURL@"]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>e8bb217c-ec91-418a-aec5-16df83dbcf82</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feshv.jpg) the result.

### Update

To use the data variable on another job (dispatched on external nodes) just pass the data value as an argument using the [job reference step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#job-reference-step).

Child job (dispatching commands/scripts to another node):

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='rdeck_srv' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>1</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>3fa71d29-e3bc-453c-a8a7-cb9e95d0a8dd</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>ChildJob</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>name: node01</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "the rundeck server is: ${option.rdeck_srv}</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>3fa71d29-e3bc-453c-a8a7-cb9e95d0a8dd</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Parent job (takes the server name and pass it to Child job):

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>e8bb217c-ec91-418a-aec5-16df83dbcf82</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>RundeckServerName</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <plugins>
          <LogFilter type='key-value-data'>
            <config>
              <invalidKeyPattern>\s|\$|\{|\}|\\</invalidKeyPattern>
              <logData>true</logData>
              <regex>^(grails.serverURL)=*(.+)$</regex>
            </config>
          </LogFilter>
        </plugins>
        <script><![CDATA[cat /etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties | grep 'grails.serverURL']]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[echo "Rundeck URL is: @data.grails.serverURL@"]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
      <command>
        <jobref name='ChildJob' nodeStep='true'>
          <arg line='-rdeck_srv ${data.grails.serverURL}' />
          <uuid>3fa71d29-e3bc-453c-a8a7-cb9e95d0a8dd</uuid>
        </jobref>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>e8bb217c-ec91-418a-aec5-16df83dbcf82</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yabV.jpg) the result.

Comment: I went ahead and submitted the request.   I like what you did exporting it. However, my jobs are run on worker nodes, not the server.  Is there a way to export a variable that is available to a different job (a project variable or something?)

Alternately, is there a way to have some workflow steps executed locally, but other run remotely?

Comment: Using the job reference step it's possible, I updated my example. Hope it helps! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this: set it as a "password" in the [key storage](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/key-storage.html).

Set up a key that contains that server's URL.  In each job, set up an [option](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#defining-an-option) that is type 'secure'.  When you select secure, it will activate a selector to choose which key to use from key storage (see [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#secure-options-using-key-storage)).   If you set the option as "required" and "hidden" it won't show up on the job run page, but will be available in the script/command.

Here is an example job:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='ServerURL' required='true' secure='true' storagePath='keys/pso/server_url' valueExposed='true'>
          <hidden>true</hidden>
        </option>
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>output</defaultTab>
    <description>Domonstrate using getting a variable from a key</description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>1</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <group>Testing stuff</group>
    <id>51b63a65-91f5-43ba-aeb9-8d640fc7a98f</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>Test job</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>.*</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <orchestrator>
      <configuration>
        <count>1</count>
      </configuration>
      <type>subset</type>
    </orchestrator>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <schedules />
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <description>Script example</description>
        <script><![CDATA[echo "This is being run from:"
echo @option.ServerURL@]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <timeZone>US/Central</timeZone>
    <uuid>51b63a65-91f5-43ba-aeb9-8d640fc7a98f</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```